# trying to pass function pointer to pthread

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to create a pthread with arguments for a function pointer, here first is the function that will be called on pthread creation..

```
void *passenger(void *arguements){
        struct arg_struct *args = arguements;
        int passenger = args->p;
        int from_floor = args->f;
        int to_floor = args->t;
        void (*enter)(int,int) = args->en;
        void (*exit)(int,int) = args->ex;
        // wait for the elevator to arrive at our origin floor, then get in
        int waiting = 1;
        while(waiting){
                if(current_floor == from_floor && state == ELEVATOR_OPEN && occupancy==0) {
                        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
                        enter(passenger, 0);
                        occupancy++;
                        waiting=0;
                        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
                }
        }

        // wait for the elevator at our destination floor, then get out
        int riding=1;
        while(riding) {
                if(current_floor == to_floor && state == ELEVATOR_OPEN){
                        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
                        exit(passenger, 0);
                        occupancy--;
                        riding=0;
                        pthread_barrier_wait(&barr);
                        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
                }
        }
}
```

and here is the calling function

```
void passenger_request(int passenger, int from_floor, int to_floor,void (*enter)(int,int), void(*exit)(int,int))
{
        pthread_mutex_lock(&passlock);
        struct arg_struct args;
        args.p = passenger;
        args.f = from_floor;
        args.t = to_floor;
        args.en = *enter;
        args.ex = *exit;
        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &passenger, &args);
        //pthread_join(thread, NULL);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&passlock);
        // wait for the elevator to arrive at our origin floor, then get in
}
```

The program is seg faulting when it creates multiple passengers on initilization, if I comment out the pthread_create line no crashing occurs. I'm assuming it's an issue with my passing of arguments for the function pointers, but I'm hazy as to what exactly is going on as all these pointers are starting to confuse me. Any help whatsoever would be much appreciated

also the struct declaration..

```
struct arg_struct{
        int p;
        int f;
        int t;
        void *(*ex)(int,int);
        void *(*en)(int,int);
};
```

Comment: Args is probably going out of scope. Learn to use gdb

Comment: Your `ex` in the struct is a pointer which points to a function returning the `void*` type value. But in the `passenger_request` function and `passenger` function, you use it as a pointer which points to a function not returning any value.

Answer (score 3):

```
args.en = *enter;
args.ex = *exit;
```

`enter` and `exit` are function pointers. Don't dereference them but rather pass them straight through via `args`. That is, you need:

```
args.en = enter;
args.ex = exit;
```

(Assuming you have correct defined `struct arg_struct` which is not shown.

Comment: Here let me show you the struct definition i forgot about that

Comment: There's a mismatch for `ex` and `en` between the struct definition and how it is used. The definition in the struct is a function pointer to a function that returns `void *`. But when it is used it is being used as a function pointer that returns `void`. And also take heed of the comment from James. Your args needs to by dynamic or global memory (if the pthread_join remains commented out).

Answer (score 2):

You are passing your new thread a pointer to args, which is defined on the stack of your passenger_request() function. As soon as passenger_request() returns, this memory could be reused, overwritten, or whatever. It is no longer guaranteed to contain what you put in it. Yet your thread still has a pointer to it and may continue to try to use it. This is likely to cause a crash, although it may be intermittent.

Try doing something different with args. If you only need it once, you could make it global. If you need multiple different ones, then allocate it on the heap with malloc:

```
void passenger_request(int passenger, int from_floor, int to_floor,void (*enter)(int,int), void(*exit)(int,int))
{
        pthread_mutex_lock(&passlock);
        struct arg_struct *args = malloc(sizeof(struct arg_struct));
        args->p = passenger;
        args->f = from_floor;
        args->t = to_floor;
        args->en = enter;
        args->ex = exit;
        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &passenger, args);
        //pthread_join(thread, NULL);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&passlock);
        // wait for the elevator to arrive at our origin floor, then get in
}
```

Then in passenger() once you're well and truly done with it, free(args).